# Correct hash function for primary keys

Tags: hash, random, md5, sha1, sha256

Wondering which hashing algorithm I should be using to create primary keys from strings.  Right now I'm using SHA-1.

In the past I've used SHA-256, although I have heard that 256 might be 'overkill' for my purposes.  I've also heard some things about maybe using MD5, but I don't know much about the pros and cons of that one.

Thanks!

Comment: hm.. what about hash collision?

Comment: SHA2 has the benefit over MD5 in that if you _do_ find a collision, you could win a fortune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a lot on your use case: whether a malicious user can gain anything if finding a collision, for starters. There is a big difference between a hashing function and a cryptographically-secure hashing algorithm. I will assume your use case is a normal programming question.

[MD5 is broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities). Seeing how that has recently caused [problems to hashing of dictionary keys in various languages](http://lwn.net/Articles/474912/), I would not use it for anything.

[SHA-1 is more and more broken as time passes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Cracking). Even though you may not need a cryptographically-secure algorithm, I would use SHA-256 unless the difference in performance is really significant, [premature optimization being evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and all that.